# How to display whole file with #include statements

Tags: linux, text-processing

Suppose I have file main.txt which contains following:

---

Some text

#include fragment1.txt

Some other text

#include fragment2.txt"

Some other text

---

where fragment1.txt and fragment2.txt looks like this:

fragment1.txt:

---

This is content of fragment1

---

fragment2.txt:

---

This is content of fragment2

---

Question: How to display whole main.txt file with "expanded" included files, like this:

---

Some text

This is content of fragment1

Some other text

This is content of fragment2

Some other text

---

Thanks

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: script not fully tested , use at your own risk .....

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `#include "file"` syntax as in C programming
language you could use `cpp` to parse it. Say, if your `main.txt`
looked like this:

```
Some text

#include "fragment1.txt"

Some other text

#include "fragment2.txt"

Some other text
```

you could do:

```
$ cpp -nostdinc -P <main.txt
Some text
This is content of fragment1
Some other text
This is content of fragment2
Some other text
```

As explained in `man cpp`:

> -nostdinc Do not search the standard system directories for header files.  Only the directories you have specified with -I options (and
>   the directory of the current file, if appropriate) are searched.
>
> -P  Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on
>   something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which
>   might be confused by the linemarkers.

Notice however that `cpp` does more than parsing `#include` lines and
depending on your use case it might be or might not be useful.  For
example, `cpp` automatically removes all C-style comments:

```
// this is a comment
/* this as a comment too /*
```

It looks useful and if you want to keep the comments you can use `-C` option.  Another thing is
that `cpp` will try to interpret all lines that start with `#` as
preprocessor directives.  For example this:

```
#define A 7
Value: A
```

would be printed as:

```
Value: 7
```

and this

```
#blah blah
```

would throw error:

```
<stdin>:14:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #blah
```

In practice, there are some programs that rely on `cpp` as their
configs parser, for example `xrdb`.

Comment: Also, lines such as `I like unix` will be scathed.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: great advice, +1 for noticing it

Answer (score 1):

a small script can solve the literal `#include`,
not recursively,  include the file itself can cause infinite loop
and recursive include is not stated as required .

eventually a real parser may needed, and you can refer to the other answers .

feed `main.txt` to the following perl script  via standard input
the output is (roughly) desired output.
awk can also do the job but i like the mystery of perl :)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
  if (/^#include (.*)/) {
    system('cat',$1);
  } else {
    print;
  }
}
```

---

A shorter, one-liner version of the above code:

```
perl -e '(/^#include (.*)/ ? system("cat",$1) : print) while <>;' <main.txt
```

For those who may interested in knowing more perl:

- `<>` is short for reading from `STDIN`, which is standard input stream
- The `while` keyword can be placed at the end of a line; and `()` can be omitted when there is no ambiguous interpretation.
- For each line read from `STDIN`, perl store it in `$_`
- `$_` is a predefined variable that most perl built-in function accepts as argument where no argument is given,
- `print` is one of the built-in function that accepts `$_`
- After reading each line, perl will evaluate the ternary expression. The regular expression match applies on `$_` by default
- When `/^#include (.*)/`  returns 1(number of match detected), indicates `$_` started with literal `#include`
- perl stores the remaining part of `$_` to `$1`, as it is the 1st grouped capture ($2,$3....are defined if there are more groups)
- The `system` function invokes a command via system shell , mostly `sh`
  in this line it invokes `cat`, and passing `$1` as its argument.
- When `/^#include (.*)/` returns 0 on `$_`, `print` is evaluated and as a side effect, it print out `$_`
- The value of ternary expression is silently ignored

Comment: from what i have read by now,  it is reasonable to assume ```#include``` is literal,  as many conf system or programming language do in this way .   and also it is very easy  to change with another literal

Comment: good approach, +1.   notes: 1. use `system()` rather than print and backticks.  e.g. `system('cat',$1);`.   2. to enable recursion of #include statements, you could run the script itself rather than `cat`.  e.g. `system($0,$1);` -- $0 is the script's own name, see `man perlvar` and search for $0 or $PROGRAM_NAME for details.  3. perl isn't mysterious.

Comment: also, it's probably a good idea to test for whether $1 can be read before including it: e.g. `if (-r $1) { system($0,$1) } else { warn "Error reading #included file '$1': $!\n"};` -- warn prints to stderr rather than stdout. You could make that a fatal error by adding, e.g., `exit 1` inside the `else` clause.

Comment: you don't need the `print` with `system()`.  that will print unwanted exit codes from each system call.

Comment: updated my answer with the ```system``` call.  i am aware of the ```$0``` variable ,however recursive include  costs much more code than now. for same reason i decide to leave file test out.  To Myself , the mystery of perl is the fact that I can write insanely  short code to complete a seemingly comprehensive task.

Comment: huh?  `system($0,$1)` is actually 3 characters shorter than `system('cat',$1)`.   for read-only processes like `cat`, it's safe enough to leave the error handling to the external program, but it could be disastrous if the external program did more than just read the input and print it out.   it's always a good idea to write your programs defensively, to minimise damage and other side-effects in case of unexpected input.

Comment: you could put that one-liner into your answer as an alternative solution, along with an explanation of how it works - the idea here is to teach, not just to provide cargo-cult copy-paste answers.

Comment: @cas thanks for the reminding . being easily  distracted by coding than teaching.

Comment: Redirection is **not** required for the one-liner.  or for the standalone version, either.  `<>` is not exactly just STDIN.  It's STDIN **and** the contents of all filename arguments.   See `man perlop` and search for `null filehandle`.

Comment: If there are any non-filename args, they need to be removed from @ARGV first, e.g. process the options using `Getopt::Std` or `Getopt::Long` or similar modules.  or roll your own with a loop over @ARGV.

Answer (score 0):

Run the C preprocessor directly:

$ cpp -P main.txt

That will do it. You will need to quote the name of the include files though:

#include "fragment1.txt"

As a bonus, you get the full power of the C preprocessor: macros, conditional inclusions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`, you can use the `e` flag to the `s` command:

```
sed 's/^#include/cat/e'
```

The replaces the `#include` with `cat` and executes it, so the line gets replaced by the answer of the `cat` command.

If the filename may contain characters like a whitespace, better quote it:

```
sed 's/^#include *\(.*\)/cat "\1"/e'
```

*But be aware that this still may fail on special filenames with backslashes, ticks and some others.*